# Selected is not working when i use v-model?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-model

I know that selected does not work if I use `v-model`, but I use `v-model` to get the selected user and use it in my firebase, so I have my html like this:

```html
<select v-model="medespeler1" class="inputbox rounded" required>
  <option v-for="(option, i) in medespelers" :key="i" :selected="selected">{{ medespelers[i] }}</option>
</select>
```

Then in the data property I got this to also get all the `medespelers` stored in the db and the `medespeler1` value:

```js
data: function() {
  return {
    medespelers:[],
    medespeler1: '',
  }
},
```

In firebase I set all the `medespelers` in an array and pass it to the data property, but because I need to send the `medespeler1` value to the data property I can not use `:selected`, because that wont work. Where do I start so that it also stores the `medespeler1` value and have a selected item in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the select is using `medespeler1` for `v-model`, all that must be done is setting the value of `medespeler1` and the `<select>` will react to it:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      medespeler1: "banana"
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="medespeler1">
     <option>apple</option>
     <option>banana</option>
     <option>cherry</option>
  </select>
  
  Selected: {{ medespeler1 }}
</div>
```